# What permissions affect fields attached to taxonomies that don't affect fields attached to content types?

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms, wysiwyg, location

On a D7 site, I created a Description field (using filtered text with ckeditor) and a Geolocation field using a Googlemap widget.

I attached them to a content type called Accommodation, and they behaved as I expected - ie, I got a rich text editor on Description, and a map on the Geolocation field, when logged in with any role that would allow me to edit a node of that content type.

I attached the same fields, with the same settings, to a Taxonomy, and found that I could only see the map and ckeditor if logged in as an administrator.

If I logged in with another role, the googlemap and rich text editor would not appear, although I was still able to create a taxonomy item, and they did appear on the same fields shown on a node create form  -  just not on the taxonomy item create form.

I have all taxonomy permissions turned on for authenticated users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving an answer in case it's useful to anyone else.

The permission that was affecting the display of taxonomy ckedit and geolocation fields was 'View the administration theme' - it looks like the Open Framework theme has a small issue when displaying taxonomy edit field forms.

I should have just changed to a default theme to test this.